# Return array from javascript function does not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which process some array in sub-process.

The goal is to send the actual array into function and return the array updated (2 values removed).

I am calling the function by:

```
var resultMaster = [];
resultMaster = traceSystem(traceURL,searchURL,term,master_id,groupID,final_pair,masters);
    console.log('resultMaster:    ' + resultMaster);
    console.log('resultSystem under Master:    ' + masters);
```

the called function does:

```
function traceSystem(traceURL,searchURL,term,master_id,groupID,pairKey,masters) {
  var   resultSystem = [];
  ...
  $.ajax({
    url: searchURL,
    type:'post',
    data: jsonQuery,
    dataType: 'text',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    success: function(response) { 
      ...
        for ( m = 0; m <  system.masters_ids.buckets.length; m++ ) {
          console.log('Removing masterID: ' + system.masters_ids.buckets[m].key); 
          masters = masters.filter(function(e) { return e != system.masters_ids.buckets[m].key }); 
          console.log('resultSystem:    ' + masters);
        };

    }   // Success
  }); //Ajax

  console.log('final result from System:    ' + masters);
  return masters;
};
```

I supposed that the `return masters;` will return the array to parent function into the variable **resultMaster**. But it doesn't.

See log from console:

```
Array [ "ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint37…", "ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint37…", "3b3_87465652", "00000553239291", "ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint37…", "ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint37…" ]
```

Logs from the loop:

```
Removing masterID: 3b3_87465652
resultSystem:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,00000553239291,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te

Removing masterID: ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te
resultSystem:    ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,00000553239291,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te
```

Log right after the loop:

```
final result from System:    ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,00000553239291,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_teindex-by-masterid.jsp:343:5
```

Log from parent function after returned value from traceSystem:

```
resultMaster:    
resultSystem under Master:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,3b3_87465652,00000553239291,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te
```

Variable resultMasters seems to be empty.

How to properly return the array from called function?

**Added based on @Quentin request:**

I have tried to create separate simple example to simulate the behavior and strange is that there is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function traceMasterId(masters) {
                var resultMaster = [],
                masters = [];

                masters.push('ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te');
                masters.push('ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te');
                masters.push('ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te');
                masters.push('ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te');
                masters.push('3b3_87465652');
                masters.push('00000553239291');

                console.log('Masters:    ' + masters);

                resultMaster = traceSystem(masters);

                console.log('resultMaster:    ' + resultMaster);
            };

            function traceSystem(masters) {
                var master_ids = [];

                master_ids.push('ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te');
                master_ids.push('3b3_87465652');

                for ( m = 0; m <  master_ids.length; m++ ) {
                    console.log('Removing masterID: ' + master_ids[m]); 
                    masters = masters.filter(function(e) { return e != master_ids[m] }); 
                    console.log('resultSystem:    ' + masters);
                };

                console.log('Final result from System:    ' + masters);
                return masters;             

            };

</script>                   

<body onload="traceMasterId();"></body>
```

See log:

```
Masters:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_te,3b3_87465652,00000553239291test.jsp:14:5
Removing masterID: ci1481536983718.923358@czcholsint372_tetest.jsp:29:6
resultSystem:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,3b3_87465652,00000553239291test.jsp:31:6
Removing masterID: 3b3_87465652test.jsp:29:6
resultSystem:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,00000553239291test.jsp:31:6
Final result from System:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,00000553239291test.jsp:34:5
resultMaster:    ci1481537045764.949410@czcholsint373_te,ci1481537045768.924200@czcholsint372_te,ci1481536983712.948609@czcholsint373_te,00000553239291test.jsp:18:5
```

I do not see a difference what has been done by other way. Except that the subfunction has been now called only with one parameter.

Comment: The code says `async: false,` — it isn't an asynchronous call.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You log a value. Return that value. Log the return result. And they are different. I can't think of any situation that would happen under. Can you make your [mcve] more *minimal* and *complete*?

Comment: Worth noting that `async: false` is [deprecated in the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning), and you should consider that browsers _could_ start throwing errors at any point, breaking your code.

Comment: @Quentin I will try ... give me a time

Comment: so it means james thorpe was correct ?

Comment: @Mahi I don't think so. True is that now I have excluded AJAX, but as you can see in first attempt I have reported and returned the **masters** value also directly from the called function. Not from the AJAX .success part.

Comment: @Quentin, it seems to be problem between chair and keyboard. I have just reformatted rows in the code and it started to work.

Probably a hidden character escaped the real return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because $.ajax() is (and should be) an asynchronous function.

What is happening is that traceSystem() function returns **before** your success callback is actually called.

So you are returning `masters` object before it is actually modified.

Server side you could have been used *deasync* (nodejs module) but in a browser I think your best bet is to rewrite your code to do it asynchronously.

That is, for example:

1. Add a *callback* argument to `traceSystem()` function.
2. Call it (passing *masters* as argument) at the end of the *success* callback of the *$.ajax()*.
3. Instead of...

this:

```
[...]
resultMaster = traceSystem(arg1, arg2...);
console.log('resultMaster: ' + resultMaster);
[...]
```

...try:

```
[...]
traceSystem(arg1, arg2... , function(resultMaster){
    console.log('resultMaster: ' + resultMaster);
    [...]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue seems to be not issue.

I have just reformatted rows in the code and it started to work.

Probably a hidden character escaped the real return value.

Comment: I don't think so: It should be a side effect of some delay (just like executing an `alert("Foo bar");`after calling your function giving the time to the ajax processing to be finished. It would fail in other browsers or in random other situations...